# Is there a polite /accepted way of "bumping" up questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

As the question title says, I was wondering if there is a good or accepted way of "bumping" old and unanswered questions to show up again on the questions list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it's even in the [faq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) --

> #### What if I don’t get a good answer?
>
> In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Comment: should have checked there first... Thanks Jeff!

Comment: If after substantially revising and improving an old question, it still hasn't been "bumped" up to the Unanswered Questions page, is there anything else I can do before trying a bounty?

Comment: Yes, but it may irritate people if you edit your question multiple times per day, multiple times per week just to "bump" it. There was one question that I asked some time ago that was never answered -- I edited it, some time later it even had a bounty, but nothing helped. It sometimes happens that your question stays unanswered for a longer time and "bumping" it wouldn't help. So I would say that "reasonable bumping" is ok, but compulsive "bumping" is something not to be encouraged.

Answer (score 5):

When you place a bounty on a question then this will also bump up the question (and in addition it will be featured in the bounty list).

But note that a bounty for unclear questions is not gonna work well. Attention is not the only thing that drives answers.