# Is there a way to bump questions asked by other users?

Tags: discussion

This question seems to handle if its one's own post : [Is there a polite /accepted way of "bumping" up questions?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/is-there-a-polite-accepted-way-of-bumping-up-questions)

I'm wondering about what the best approach is if I see an old question that hasn't had any responses, or could do with more. Is there an accepted way to bring it to the attention of others?

Comment: The best way to do that is to answer it yourself with a genuine answer. Naturally anyone can like a question without knowing an answer, but that's still true. The next best way is to make an edit that genuinely improves the question's presentation. Otherwise I think not. The converse of this is why is this not allowed as a direct action? Thinking about that is revealing.

Comment: As @mkt implies, the "I think not" above is wrong. I just forgot to mention bounties. (The primary association for me of bounty remains that of a chocolate bar.)

Comment: I wonder whether the ability to bump a question would be a privilege that would be worth proposing. Perhaps for trusted users, e.g., people holding a silver tag badge for one of the tags on the question. Thoughts?

Comment: There's also an unpolite way, but I guess that's obvious.

Answer (score 8):

One way is to offer a bounty on the question. As a mild bonus, you get a badge the first time you do this (Investor).